# Can't turn off Facebook Secure Browsing

Tags: facebook, security, ssl

I'm developing a Facebook canvas app. I don't have a SSL certificate so I've been using a plain http:// URL + sandbox mode for the creation and testing process.

Suddenly I realized my Facebook account turned to Secure Browsing mode and I'm unable to turn it off via *Account Settings >> Security >> Secure Browsing*. There is no "edit" button. None of my co-workers experienced the same problem. Their Secure Browsing option is off, editable and the app is visible. Anyone familiar with the same issue?

Comment: It looks to be something they are (annoyingly) rolling out, as some accounts can still disable and others can't.

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing your app you shouldn't really need to disable HTTPS, nor is that really a representative test if you're using HTTP but almost all your users will be using HTTPS (as is the case with Facebook)

It'd be better to get a free cert from startssl.com or similar free CAs, use OpenSSL to generate an in-house CA or self-signed certs, or accept the certificate warnings from the default cert that ships in your webserver, if any, than to disable the secure browsing option on your Facebook account for this purpose;

As for the option itself in the Facebook setting, that's somewhat off topic for here, and I'm unsure what the exact status is but I believe the option to browse Facebook insecurely is being phased out

Another option for testing is to run a test server with a separate proxy to your production environment (e.g nginx) for test purposes and log all the traffic to that server for debugging